# Text spanning over multiply colums

Tags: html, css

So I am working on a tumblr page and what I want are collapsible divs that span over multiply columns. I managed to get the divs to collaps and to span over multiply columns. The problem is the content inside those divs. They span over multiply columns when I want the content to stay in it's own column. I've added a column-span but it didn't do anything.

CSS:

```
.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.content {
  column-span: 1;
  width:250px;
  max-height:0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: ;
}

#columns {
    column-span: 1;
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 840px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 0px;
}

/* Body */

body {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#container {
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:700px;
}

#calender {
    width:250px;
    margin-left:-18px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding: 0 18px;
}

.calender-month {
    width:250px;
    height:36px;
    padding-top:4px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Bebas Neue;
    font-size:18pt;
    text-align:center;
    background:#aabca6;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    border:none;
}

#calender-border {
    height:30px;
    border:1px #e7e7e7 solid;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

.calender-date {
    float:left;
    width:30px;
    padding-top:4px;
    padding-bottom:4px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family: Nunito;
    font-size:12pt;
    text-align:center;
    background:#f2bfad;
}

.calender-input {
    float:right;
    width:213px;
    padding-top:4px;
    padding-bottom:4px;
    padding-left:4px;
    font-family: Nunito;
    font-size:12pt;
    background:#fff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

  <section id="columns">

<!-- CALENDER-->

<button class="calender-month">January</button>
<div class="content">

    <div id="calender-border">
    <div class="calender-date">05</div> <div class="calender-input">Gun Napat 98'</div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="calender-border">
<div class="calender-date">12</div> <div class="calender-input">Boom Krittapak 01'</div>
    </div>
    
      <div id="calender-border">
    <div class="calender-date">20</div> <div class="calender-input">Off Jumpol 91'</div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="calender-border">
<div class="calender-date">23</div> <div class="calender-input">Nat Sakdatorn 83'</div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="calender-border">
<div class="calender-date">27</div> <div class="calender-input">Benjamin Brasier 97'</div>
    </div>
    
       <div id="calender-border">
    <div class="calender-date">30</div> <div class="calender-input">New Thitipoom 93'</div>
    </div>
    
     <div id="calender-border">
<div class="calender-date">31</div> <div class="calender-input">Copter Panuwat 97'</div>
    </div>

</div>

</div>
```

[Live preview is here](https://winachawin.tumblr.com/test)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is what you want. Try to remove the `column-count: 3;` on `#columns`

Comment: No I still want the div's to span over multiply columns. I just don't want the content inside those divs to do the same thing. So january, may and september should be next to each other. Just the content inside january should not be in the same column as may.

Comment: put the snippet code in here, so we can figure it out.